# Radiobox check from database using php

Tags: php, cakephp, radio-button

Suppose that I have the code php as below:

```
<?php
    include("connectdb.php");
    $check1 = "";
    $check2 = "";
    $check3 = "";
    $check4 = "";
    $check5 = "";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblworkfaire";
    $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if($res){
            while($data = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                if($data['1.DesTechnique'] == 1){
                    $check1 = "CHECKED";    
                    echo $check1;
                }
                else if($data['1.DesTechnique'] == 2){
                    $check2 = " CHECKED";   
                }
                else if($data['1.DesTechnique'] == 3){
                    $check3 = "CHECKED";    
                }
                else if($data['1.DesTechnique'] == 4){
                    $check4 = "CHECKED";    
                }
                else if($data['1.DesTechnique'] == 5){
                    $check5 = "CHECKED";    
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "Fail";
        }
```

?>

**And Html code:**

```
 <form  action="word2html.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="number1" value="1" checked="<? $check1; ?>">
            </b><b>
            <input name="number1" type="radio" value="2" checked="<? $check2; ?>">
            </b><b>
            <input name="number1" type="radio" value="3" checked="<? $check3; ?>">
            </b><b>
            <input  name="number1" type="radio" value="4" checked="<? $check4; ?>">
            </b><b>
            <input name="number1" type="radio" value="5" checked="<? $check5; ?>">
            </b>
```

**What I need:**

I have stored the radio box value in database,if I select value from database equal 1,it will check the radio box that have the value equal 1.

**Problem:**

I can only select value of radio box from database and it dose not work.How do I fix this? Anyone help me please, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's some rather horrible code.

First problem: You're doing a `while()` loop to fetch results from your query. If you're fetching multiple rows of data, the you'll be setting all or some of those `$checkX` variables, yet not actually doing anyhing with them during that particular loop iteration. Assuming you fetch enough rows, eventually ALL of those variables will be `checked` and you end up selecting all of your radio buttons.

If you're expecting only a single row of data, then the while() is simply cargo cult programming.

Second problem. You've repeated a lot of code in there, and define a lot of variables, for something that could be done far easier/cleaner with a loop. e.g.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
   $checked = ($data['1.DesTechnique'] == $i) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
   echo <<<EOL
<input name="number1" type="radio" value="$i"$checked>$i<br />

EOL;
}
```

No $checkX variables, no repeated inputs. just a nice loop doing the output for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to output your variables.

```
<input type="radio" name="number1" value="1" checked="<?php echo $check1; ?>">
```